# How can I represent a decreasing summation which the highest value is the starting value?

Tags: summation, notation, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursion

I am trying to find the recurrence of 
$ T(n) = 2T(n-1) + n^2$ 
 The answer it's $O(2^n n^2)$ but now I'm trying to 
find the answer using recursion and all good, but trying to find $T(n-k)$ is killing me

 I end up with this: 
$T(n) = 2T(n-1) +n^2$ 
$T(n-1) = 2T(n-2)+(n-1)^2+n^2$
$2T(n-1) = 4T(n-2) +2(n-1)^2+2n^2$
 All together I won't type with $T(n-2)$ because it was super confusing and maybe wrong
$T(n) = 2*({2T(n-2)+(n-1)^2+n^2)}+n^2$ then $T(n) = 4T(n-2)+ 2(n-1)^2+2n^2 + n^2$

End we end up with a crazy long equation...
But if we do it $k$ times and there comes my question
$T(n-k) = 2^{k+1}T(n-k-1) + \bf 2^k(n-k)^2 + ... $ a summation which elements
 the first are always being multiplied like for example a for loop such as 
`for(int i = k ; i > 0; i++)`
$result= result + 2^k(n - k)$ 
 Is there any math symbol that can represent this "decreasing summation" ? 
Even if everything is wrong I which symbol I could use for a summation which the index needs to go to zero.

Thank you

Comment: There is an error somewhere, as $T(n)=O(2^n)$. For example if $T(1)=1$ then the recurrence has the solution $T(n) = 6\cdot 2^n -(n^2+4n+6)$.